# Add new dimension dynamically to an array using recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, recursion

I have an array like this:

```
0: "SuSPENSE"
1: "Subcontractor Expense"
2: "Data Entry"
3: "Design"
4: "Programming"
5: "Subcontractor Expense - Other"
6: "Total Subcontractor Expense"
7: "Technology-Communication"
8: "Licenses"
9: "Domain Hosting Fee"
10: "Internet"
11: "Internet Servers"
12: "Internet - Other"
13: "Total Internet"
14: "Telephone"
15: "Call Center"
16: "Cellular Phones"
17: "Fax"
18: "Telephone - Other"
19: "Total Telephone"
20: "Hardware/Software"
21: "Computer Software"
22: "Hardware/Software - Other"
23: "Total Hardware/Software"
24: "Technology-Communication - Other"
25: "Total Technology-Communication"
```

This is a list of categories and subcategories. For example, `"Subcontractor Expense"` is a sub-category and ends with `"Total Subcontractor Expense"`. Same for `"Internet"` and `"Total Internet"`. The template is always the same, category starts with "(name)" and ends with "Total (name)". But each category can have many levels of sub-categories, like a tree. I'm trying to parse this array into a JSON-like array or a multidimensional array using recursive function, but I never know what the maximum depth is. I tried to do the following using `js`:

```
var parsedArray = [];
var items = getLineItems("Expense", "Total Expense"); //This is a function to return the mentioned array
var newArray = parseArray(items, "Expense");

function parseArray(items, category){
    var lineItems = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        var inArray = $.inArray("Total " + items[i], items);
        if(inArray !== -1){
            parseArray(getLineItems(items[i], "Total " + items[i]), items[i]);
        }
        else {
            lineItems.push(items[i]);
        }
    }
    parsedArray[category] = lineItems;
}
```

But this recursive function never goes deeper then 2 levels. Is is possible to generate something like this?

```
"SuSPENSE"
"Subcontractor Expense"
    "Data Entry"
    "Design"
    "Programming"
"Subcontractor Expense - Other"
"Technology-Communication"
    "Licenses"
    "Domain Hosting Fee"
    "Internet"
        "Internet Servers"
        "Internet - Other"
    "Telephone"
        "Call Center"
        "Cellular Phones"
        "Fax"
        "Telephone - Other"
    "Hardware/Software"
        "Computer Software"
        "Hardware/Software - Other"
    "Technology-Communication - Other"
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the logic you are going for here to decide what should be nested under what. I guess for each item `x` you look for a corresponding item `Total x` and everything between that pair is supposed to be nested under `x`? But then you have `SuSPENSE` just orphaned at the top for some reason? This seems like a pretty fragile structure to start with.

Comment: @MattBurland Yes, the part from X to Total X should be nested (And it might have other totals inside). SuSPENSE is a single line, which does not have any other fields, therefore it does not need Total SuSPENSE either. From linear array I'm trying to generate a multidimensional array as shown above. Initially, the data comes from Excel file and it's just an array which needs to be parsed in order to display everything properly and save into DB

Comment: What is your expected output format?  I understand the nesting and the rules which drive it.  But what are you looking for in a final structure?  Something like `[{name: 'SuSPENCE'}, {name: 'Subcontractor Expense', children: [{name: 'Data Entry'}, {name: 'Design'}, {name: 'Programming}]}, {name: 'Subcontractor Expense -Other'}, ...]` ?  Or something else entirely?

Comment: @ScottSauyet The result should be an array like this: [SuSPENSE: "SuSPENSE", Subcontractor Expense: [Data Entry: "Data Entry", Design: "Design", Programming: "Programming"], Technology-Communication: [Licenses: "Licenses", Domain Hosting Fee: "Domain Hosting Fee", internet: [Internet Servers: "Internet Servers", Internet - Other: "Internet - Other"], Telephone: [Call Center: "Call Center", Fax: "Fax"], etc]]

Comment: That's not a legitimate JS format. You need something that can be structured in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by checking if the current element has the corresponding element that starts with the word `Total` and then continues with the text of the current element and if so you increment the level. When the current element starts with word total then you decrement the level.

```js
const data = {"0":"SuSPENSE","1":"Subcontractor Expense","2":"Data Entry","3":"Design","4":"Programming","5":"Subcontractor Expense - Other","6":"Total Subcontractor Expense","7":"Technology-Communication","8":"Licenses","9":"Domain Hosting Fee","10":"Internet","11":"Internet Servers","12":"Internet - Other","13":"Total Internet","14":"Telephone","15":"Call Center","16":"Cellular Phones","17":"Fax","18":"Telephone - Other","19":"Total Telephone","20":"Hardware/Software","21":"Computer Software","22":"Hardware/Software - Other","23":"Total Hardware/Software","24":"Technology-Communication - Other","25":"Total Technology-Communication"}

function toNested(data) {
  const result = [];
  const levels = [result]
  let level = 0;

  const checkChildren = (string, data) => {
    return data.some(e => e === `Total ${string}`)
  }

  data.forEach((e, i) => {
    const object = { name: e, children: []}
    levels[level + 1] = object.children;

    if (e.startsWith('Total')) level--;
    else levels[level].push(object);

    if (checkChildren(e, data.slice(i))) level++;
  })

  return result;
}

const result = toNested(Object.values(data));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: One potential brittleness: if we inserted, say "Total Phone" after "Fax", it would entirely mess with the remaining nesting structure.  The OP may know that this is not possible, but it's a potential concern.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still guessing about your output format.  Here is a recursive solution that gives the format I asked about in the comments:

```
[
    {name: "SuSPENSE"},
    {name: "Subcontractor Expense", children: [
        {name: "Data Entry"},
        {name: "Design"},
        {name: "Programming"},
        {name: "Subcontractor Expense - Other"}
    ]},
    {name: "Technology-Communication", children: [
       //...
    ]}
]
```

```js
const restructure = (
  [s = undefined, ...ss], 
  index = s == undefined ? -1 : ss .indexOf ('Total ' + s)
) => 
  s == undefined
    ? []
    : index > -1
      ? [
          {name: s, children: restructure (ss .slice (0, index))}, 
          ... restructure (ss .slice (index + 1))
        ]
      : [{name: s}, ... restructure (ss)]

const data = ["SuSPENSE", "Subcontractor Expense", "Data Entry", "Design", "Programming", "Subcontractor Expense - Other", "Total Subcontractor Expense", "Technology-Communication", "Licenses", "Domain Hosting Fee", "Internet", "Internet Servers", "Internet - Other", "Total Internet", "Telephone", "Call Center", "Cellular Phones", "Fax", "Telephone - Other", "Total Telephone", "Hardware/Software", "Computer Software", "Hardware/Software - Other", "Total Hardware/Software", "Technology-Communication - Other", "Total Technology-Communication"]

console .log (
  restructure (data)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that in one of the recursive cases, we call our main function twice.  Once for the nested data and once for the remainder of the array.

Another possible structure, one which I like less, but which might meet your needs, looks like this:

```js
[
    "SuSPENSE",
    {"Subcontractor Expense": [
        "Data Entry", "Design", "Programming", "Subcontractor Expense - Other"
    ]},
    { "Technology-Communication": [ 
        // ...
    ]}
]
```

This could be achieved with only a minor modification:

```js
const restructure = (
  [s = undefined, ...ss], 
  index = s == undefined ? -1 : ss .indexOf ('Total ' + s)
) => 
  s == undefined
    ? []
  : index > -1
    ? [
        {[s]: restructure (ss .slice (0, index))}, 
        ... restructure (ss .slice (index + 1))
      ]
    : [s, ... restructure (ss)]
```

### Update

This variant does the same as the first, but may look more familiar to people not used to my expression-heavy style:

```js
const restructure = ([s = undefined, ...ss]) => {
  if (s == undefined) {return []}
  const index = ss .indexOf ('Total ' + s)
  return index < 0
    ? [{name: s}, ... restructure (ss)]
    : [
        {name: s, children: restructure (ss .slice (0, index))}, 
        ... restructure (ss .slice (index + 1))
      ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I can't mark 2 correct answers, but your code also worked perfectly!

Comment: this should be accepted answer, its much more clear and pitfalls proof